# mocha-allure-report allure.createAttachment is not a function

Tags: testing, mocha.js, allure

const allure = require('mocha-allure-reporter');

describe("test module1",function(){

```
before(async ()=>{
    this.timeout(10000);
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false,ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,devtools:false,
        defaultArgs: ['--auto-accept-camera-and-microphone-capture']})//--auto-accept-camera-and-microphone-capture
        
    page = await browser.newPage()
    // await Promise.all([
    //     page.setPermission('camera', { state: 'granted' }),
    //     page.setPermission('microphone', { state: 'granted' }),
    //   ]);
    // await page.setPermission('camera', { state: 'granted' })
    // await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1');
    await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 1000});
    await page.goto("https://xxxx.com");
});
after(async ()=>{
    await browser.close();
})
```

it("test",async function(){
this.timeout(30000);
await delay(3000)
const ele = await page.$("#scandocument");
await ele.click();
await delay(3000);

```
    // await page.evaluate(() => {
    //     window.confirm = () => true;
    //   });
      
    const mainContainer = await page.$("#dwtcontrolContainer");
    await mainContainer.screenshot({path:'./Images/TempImages/testCamera.png'});
    const num1 = await compareImages("./Images/TempImages/testCamera.png",'./Images/ExpectedImages/testCamera.png','./Images/DiffImages/diff_testCamera.png');
    console.log(num1);

    const attachment1 = fs.readFileSync('./Images/TempImages/testCamera.png');
    const attachment2 = fs.readFileSync('./Images/ExpectedImages/testCamera.png')
    const attachment3= fs.readFileSync('./Images/DiffImages/diff_testCamera.png')
    allure.addAttachment('Screenshot',attachment1, 'image/png');
    allure.addAttachment('ExpectedImage',attachment2, 'image/png');
    allure.addAttachment('DiffImage', attachment3,'image/png');
    assert.equal(num1,0);
})
```

})
when I run the testcase it throught out error  allure.addAttachment is not a function,how could I solve this problem?

when I run the testcase it throught out error  allure.addAttachment is not a function,how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try 'allure.createAttachment(....)' instead

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-allure-reporter

Comment: I tried allure.createAttachment(....) but it also throught out error allure.createAttachment is not a function

Comment: have you declared allure as a const? "declare const allure: any" (TS version but you can see the similar bit if you use JS). I'm using it with Protractor and this is how I do my tie-ins with the Jasmine-Allure reporter (it's an ugly declaration but it works).

Compare to this demo code btw. The dev doc spells it as "createAttachement" instead of "createAttachment" btw. Try Both.
https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-mocha-example/blob/ab117edc0fda1e224e141bb1d1f08a6e7e01d378/test/webdriver-io.spec.js#L25